# Change displayed value of DataSet column dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I had this fixed a few months back and it must have just left my mind entirely, and since I just updated my data model on my MVC3 site (update model from db) it is broken again. I am getting the

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

error. There are plenty of questions out already on this talking about changing some settings in the web.config, but I haven't ever been able to get those to work. The last time I fixed it I am 99% certain I changed something in this generated file:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Blog))]
[KnownType(typeof(Comment))]
public partial class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    //[SOMETHING HERE??]
    [DataMember]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

But I cannot for the life of me remember what, and I am not sure what words to search for on the web.

And I know that editing generated code is a big dumb thing to do, but I haven't figured out how to get around that just yet.

Comment: OK, so I got around the error by adding the validateinput(false) attribute on the controller. But I thought there was another way. By doing this don't I leave every view on that controller open to XSS attacks?

Comment: Simply put validateinput(false) on the controller action that requires it. Doesn't need to be on the entire controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[AllowHtml]
[DataMember]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

> And I know that editing generated code is a big dumb thing to do, but
>   I haven't figured out how to get around that just yet.

The problem is that you are passing your WCF domain entities to/from views which is a very bad design approach.

The correct way is to use view models. View models are classes that you specifically design to meet the requirements of your views and then you only pass view models to the views. You will then map between your domain models and view models. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is a great tool to simplify this task.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the call out on using ViewModels. I had seen it implemented in a few places here and there, but for some reason I thought it wasn't needed in an MVC pattern. Obviously I am seeing the error of my ways now. I'll check out AutoMapper tonight